# PayPal in android

Tags: android, paypal

In my application I need to include the PayPal . If I simply give the URL of the page(which is in HTML) that I want the user to redirect to and does not integrate SDK will it work in an app ? Thanks!

Comment: Check out how the PayPal portion launches a new Intent from the android-donations-lib library on GitHub. This opens a web browser for the user to finish the transaction.

Comment: @myninjaname thanks for your reply .. so you mean to say that it is possible through URL only.. Can you redirect me to that link .. I shall be grateful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SDK is not necessary, you can use a URL/launch a browser.

Check out how the PayPal portion launches a new Intent from the android-donations-lib library on GitHub. This opens a web browser for the user to finish the transaction.

[android-donations-lib](https://github.com/dschuermann/android-donations-lib)